# Two touch events (touch / touch and drag) on 1 ViewController, but I want 'touch and drag' to fire independently

Tags: objective-c

I have 2 images on one ViewController. When I tap the view, image1 jumps.  For image2, I can touch and drag the image around the view.  My problem is that when I touch image2 to drag, image1 jumps. I don't want image1 to jump when dragging image2.

I was thinking I could accomplish this without UIGestureRecognizer; just using a simple if statement.  Is that possible?

The mess I have so far...
**and please note**, because I've been at this for a while, my code for this doesn't make whole lot of sense, because nothing I'm trying is working, so I stripped it out. I just feel it should be as simple as, if image2 touch and drag event is happening, then image1's touch event should not.

GameViewController.h

```
bool flicked;
```

GameViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)startGame:(id)sender {
flicked = 0;

//start game code...

}
```

IMAGE2 - This image can be dragged around the view

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
//flicked = 1;
UITouch *myTouch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
Image2.center = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];
//flicked = 0;
}
```

IMAGE1 - This image jumps when view is tapped

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

if ((flicked = 0)) //OR (!flicked)?
{
    image1jump = 30;
}
else {

image1jump = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing two UIGestureRecognizers, one on the single tap imageView, and another on the touch and drag ImageView.  Set them accordingly (likely a tapGestureRecognizer and a PanGesturecognizer).  It's hard to imagine a scenario where overriding the touch handling methods will be easier than a gesture recognizer for what your describing.